# Como manter o rodapé sempre lá em baixo

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Queria saber como manter o rodapé do site sempre na parte inferior do site, mesmo que o conteúdo do site seja pouco, como o exemplo abaixo.

[image: Exemplo]

Se eu colocar um margin top, ele não fica lá em baixo em todas as resoluções, tentei com porcentagem e também não consegui.

Comment: já tentou `bottom: 0px`?

Comment: Não tinha tentado, valeu ai @TobyMosque deu certinho!!

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples Utiliza o exemplo com o nome de:
**Sticky footer**

Comment: Valeu ai @João, não queria usar bootstrap, pq é uma pagina simples, só faltava ajustar o footer, mas nesse exemplo tem um css só para isso, gostei bastante valeu!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

você pode fixar um elemento no final da pagina usando `position` `fixed` ou `absolute` e setar o `bottom` para `0px`.

Segue um exemplo com `header` and `footer` fixos e a `section` com largura fixa e centralizada na pagina.

```js
var showContent = document.getElementById("showContent");
var content = document.getElementById("content");

showContent.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
 content.classList.remove("invisivel");
    showContent.classList.add("invisivel");
});
```

```css
body, html {
    position: absolute;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

section {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;    
    z-index: 0;
}

section #container {
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

header,
footer {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    z-index: 1;
}

header {
    top: 0px;
}

footer {
    bottom: 0px;
}

.invisivel {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section>
  <div id="container">
    <input id="showContent" type="button" value="Exibir Conteudo" /> 
    <div id="content" class="invisivel">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc tincidunt efficitur fermentum. Integer viverra tristique diam eget commodo. Aliquam faucibus velit nec porttitor fermentum. Aliquam tristique tempor sem nec aliquam. Etiam id lorem at tellus iaculis iaculis. Donec tincidunt lectus sed dolor tincidunt efficitur. Cras eu neque ex. Vestibulum eu volutpat lectus. Suspendisse varius, turpis quis aliquam dapibus, ligula ligula facilisis nunc, id tincidunt nulla massa sit amet mauris. Praesent sed ex id neque sagittis egestas laoreet eget purus. Nunc egestas consequat tellus, ut ullamcorper eros facilisis eu. Maecenas a lorem nisi.
      </p>
      <p>
        Cras faucibus velit at lorem laoreet, sed vulputate eros venenatis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque enim eros, varius eget cursus ut, euismod quis nisl. Integer volutpat tempus velit. Ut turpis lorem, facilisis a consequat in, tincidunt sit amet felis. Nulla imperdiet leo eget justo consequat, nec luctus odio sodales. Etiam urna est, lobortis in tristique at, tincidunt a ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque tincidunt id ipsum in rutrum. Donec tempor id ligula nec consectetur. Mauris mattis, mi quis consequat tincidunt, turpis quam faucibus risus, ac iaculis nunc sapien quis lorem.
      </p>
      <p>
        Nunc finibus tortor ipsum, quis maximus sapien pharetra vel. Mauris auctor rutrum est, ut fringilla nisi auctor id. Sed lacinia laoreet rutrum. Nulla eget volutpat lacus, ac ullamcorper mi. Aenean consequat vulputate molestie. Ut dictum arcu sit amet elit vehicula posuere. Curabitur gravida, eros vestibulum mollis faucibus, quam tellus laoreet nibh, ut viverra est nulla non lacus. Proin mollis tortor eget orci convallis, et posuere turpis congue. Pellentesque accumsan, lorem non dapibus dapibus, dolor risus aliquam purus, vel vestibulum orci sem non arcu. Etiam accumsan sollicitudin libero. Suspendisse tristique, tortor eu tristique vehicula, lectus nibh tempus orci, eget elementum magna libero non nibh. Mauris dapibus quam nec finibus eleifend. Curabitur ut lacus at velit vulputate fringilla. Duis cursus dictum nulla, porta pellentesque nulla consequat eu. Aenean elementum condimentum metus et pharetra.
      </p>
      <p>
        Fusce varius metus eu nibh porta, sit amet facilisis sapien dapibus. Pellentesque ullamcorper dui leo, vitae tristique massa molestie vitae. Morbi sit amet mauris non eros lobortis vestibulum eu et orci. Quisque in massa at quam malesuada consequat vel vitae augue. Aenean ut purus elementum, malesuada risus sodales, varius neque. Aenean gravida congue diam, id finibus felis vulputate in. Curabitur mattis quis erat at porta. Fusce non congue massa, at convallis justo.
      </p>
      <p>
        Sed pellentesque diam eu nibh finibus, vitae euismod diam blandit. Ut luctus, massa gravida efficitur pretium, eros felis ullamcorper quam, vitae tempor sapien lectus commodo enim. Nunc eget mi eget nibh posuere interdum quis sed nibh. Phasellus iaculis luctus dapibus. Vestibulum at finibus urna, lobortis maximus erat. Donec maximus risus id est tristique rutrum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas blandit, lacus eu semper finibus, elit sapien eleifend justo, in vehicula libero lacus imperdiet elit. Vestibulum lacus odio, luctus eu ex eget, efficitur ultrices est. In eget eleifend ex.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 7):

Para mim a maneira mais sensata e sem gambiarra é utilizar o calc, com ele você evita utilizar position absolute ou javascript forçando muitas vezes o reflow e sobreposição de elementos com z-index, sem falar que evita diversos bugs e é suportado em quase todos os navegadores, com exceção de alguns browsers para mobile.. Porem não me preocupo com isso, pois geralmente há rolagem no eixo vertical da pagina no mobile. Utilizo o seguinte code:

```
main {
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 100px);
    min-height:    -moz-calc(100vh - 100px);
    min-height:         calc(100vh - 100px);
}

//100px é a altura do footer

footer {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Ex.:

```css
/*reset*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  background-color: rgb(201, 225, 222);
  display: block;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 100px);
  min-height: -moz-calc(100vh - 100px);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
footer {
  background-color: rgb(0, 55, 96);
  display: block;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

Se quiser uma solução mais simples:

```css
html,
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
#header {
  padding:10px;
  background:#5ee;
}
#content {
  padding:10px;
  padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background:#ee5;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Criei a seguinte solução em Javascript, pode ser que haja outras maneiras de fazer, mas eu fiz assim.

Explicando o código:

O que fiz foi o seguinte, fiz com que quando a página fosse carregada ou redimencionada, executasse uma função. Essa função avalia se o rodape esta em uma posição mais alta do que a parte inferior da janela, caso sim o posiciona usando os seguintes valores para a margem inferior da div conteudo:

- tamanhoTela => altura da janela
- topo.offsetHeight => altura da div topo
- conteudo.offsetHeight => altura da div conteudo
- rodape.offsetHeight => altura da div rodape
- 20 => margem superior da div conteudo

Caso contrário aplica apenas uma margem de 20px para a div conteudo.

```js
window.onload = posicionaRodape;
window.onresize = posicionaRodape;

function posicionaRodape() {
  var topo = document.querySelector("#topo");

  var conteudo = document.querySelector("#conteudo");

  var rodape = document.querySelector("#rodape");

  var tamanhoTela = window.innerHeight;

  if (rodape.offsetTop < tamanhoTela - rodape.offsetHeight) {
    conteudo.style.marginBottom = (tamanhoTela - topo.offsetHeight - conteudo.offsetHeight - rodape.offsetHeight - 20) + "px";
  } else {
    conteudo.style.marginBottom = "20px";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
#topo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #555;
}
#conteudo {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #555;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#rodape {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="topo" onclick="alert(window.innerHeight)"></div>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
<div id="rodape"></div>
```

Dessa maneira você terá um rodapé que não ficará fixo caso a div conteudo seja grande e haja scroll na página, e também não terá o rodape se sobrepondo ao conteudo caso o mesmo seja grande a ponto de fazer a página ter scroll.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

#### Rodapé na parte inferior do Documento

Eu costumo utilizar a seguinte solução:

Primeiro calculo a altura da janela `windowHeight` e dessa altura subtraio a altura do cabeçalho `headerHeight` e do rodapé `footerHeight` então aplico o resultado na altura mínima do conteúdo:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  // Aplica a altura toda vez que a janela for redimensionada 
  $(window).resize(function(event){

    // Altura da Janela
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    
    // Altura do Cabeçalho (com margins e paddings)
    var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(true, true);
    
    // Altura do Rodapé (com margins e paddings)
    var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight(true, true);
    
    // Altura mínima calculada
    var contentHeight = Math.floor(windowHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight);
    
    // Aplica a altura mínima necessária para que o footer encoste na parte
    // inferior da janela
    $('section').css('min-height', contentHeight);
  
  }).resize(); // Executa o evento uma vez para que seja aplicada as correções

});
```

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
header, section, footer{
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:80px;
}

header{
  background-color:#764895;
  height:80px;
}
section{
  background-color:#053057;
}
footer{
  background-color:#549276;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>Cabeçalho</header>
<section>Conteúdo</section>
<footer>Rodapé</footer>
```

Caso o conteúdo ultrapasse a altura da janela, nada acontecerá visualmente, pois estamos especificando a altura mínima e não a máxima ou específica. Apenas estamos dizendo que não pode ficar menor do que `X` pixels, mas não tem nenhum problema se ficar maior.

#### Rodapé na parte inferior da Janela

Agora, para que a rodapé fique sempre visível, mesmo quando há conteúdo suficiente para criar rolagem na página, utilize `position:fixed;` da seguinte forma:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  // Altura do Cabeçalho (com margins e paddings)
  var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(true, true);
    
  // Altura do Rodapé (com margins e paddings)
  var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight(true, true);
    
  // Aplica uma margem superior no conteúdo do tamanho do cabeçalho, para que
  // o conteúdo seja visível desde o início
  $('section').css('margin-top', headerHeight);
  
  // Aplica uma margem inferior no conteúdo do tamnho do rodapé, para que 
  // o conteúdo seja visível até a última informação
  $('section').css('margin-bottom', footerHeight);
  
  
  // Aplica a altura toda vez que a janela for redimensionada 
  $(window).resize(function(event){

    // Altura da Janela
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        
    // Altura do Cabeçalho (com margins e paddings)
    var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight(true, true);
    
    // Altura do Rodapé (com margins e paddings)
    var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight(true, true);
        
    // Altura mínima calculada
    var contentHeight = Math.floor(windowHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight);
        
    // Aplica a altura mínima necessária para que o footer encoste na parte
    // inferior da janela
    $('section').css('min-height', contentHeight);
      
  }).resize(); // Executa o evento uma vez para que seja aplicada as correções
  
  

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
body{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:Lato;}
header, section, footer{
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
}

header{
  position:fixed;
  background-color:#764895;
  line-height:80px;
  height:80px;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
section{
  background-color:#053057;
}
footer{
  position:fixed;
  background-color:#549276;
  line-height:30px;
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<header>Cabeçalho</header>
<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt voluptate sequi hic dignissimos vel? Sed veniam deleniti dolor, voluptas. Aliquam eius temporibus magnam iure doloribus maxime, impedit cum provident eligendi!</p>
<p>Corporis incidunt, maiores. Recusandae, eveniet corporis est esse ratione quibusdam ipsam deserunt earum a rem id neque aspernatur quos commodi consequuntur non deleniti. Culpa, autem nulla sint, mollitia maiores nobis?</p>
<p>Ratione ipsum sed quis aperiam repellat eum distinctio nemo? Error obcaecati, hic nisi esse, possimus sed qui dolor, corrupti aut nobis molestiae totam. Numquam maiores explicabo ipsum error iusto id.</p>
<p>Nam temporibus labore magnam, sapiente officia beatae quasi libero sequi. Architecto, nostrum! Itaque doloremque nostrum eveniet illo sed reprehenderit, impedit perspiciatis officiis ratione tenetur eligendi placeat explicabo, suscipit laudantium. Earum.</p>
<p>Est eum voluptas aperiam nesciunt doloremque ipsum, architecto nihil, perferendis nam harum natus commodi quam molestias distinctio inventore illo! Nemo minus iste, adipisci totam autem aspernatur, architecto ipsum dicta nam.</p>
<p>Labore deserunt rerum quam alias corporis saepe soluta non perferendis, rem! Repellat repellendus explicabo dolore a aliquam nobis voluptate qui est ea, molestias aperiam dolorum accusantium minima quos consequuntur illo.</p>
<p>Saepe voluptatem aliquam, cumque alias maiores labore debitis atque temporibus et iste magni aut consectetur fugiat ab iure mollitia ea neque ad delectus! Sit earum, repudiandae voluptatum maxime, eos dolorum.</p>
<p>Labore inventore aliquam magnam aspernatur. Numquam officiis illo suscipit quidem nostrum quibusdam id veniam, corrupti temporibus molestias, aperiam voluptatem impedit odit totam pariatur? Sed repellendus nam, reiciendis dolore, suscipit libero.</p>
<p>Rem unde quasi minima, nemo porro nihil accusantium tempore eius placeat atque aut aspernatur explicabo ipsa nesciunt natus delectus. Consectetur possimus fugiat quod asperiores repudiandae quaerat adipisci dolor libero iusto.</p>
<p>Porro omnis cum vitae culpa aliquam, optio provident nesciunt perspiciatis ea doloremque totam sequi magni cumque suscipit error voluptates, quam earum dolorum molestias voluptas perferendis esse. Dolores, ipsam amet at.</p>
</section>
<footer>Rodapé</footer>
```

Comment: Valeu ai Kadu, achei meio "complexo", consegui fazer de outra forma, mas valeu mesmo, gostei da sua solução, eu não conhecia essa forma de pegar a altura a página.