# posicionar [em qualquer situação] o rodapé no final da página

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte **HTML**:

```
<body>

    <div class="todo">
        <button class='button'>Login</button>
        <div class="topo">
            <h1 class="h1Centralizado">
                <?php echo $constantes->getTituloSite(); ?>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cont">
                <?php require_once("indexConteudo.php"); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="final">
                <?php require_once("celula/_requeridos/final.php"); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

E o seguinte **CSS**:

```
html, body, .todo {
    min-height:100%
}
html {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 1em;
    background-image: radial-gradient(rgb(172,204,193) 20%, rgb(40, 22, 111));
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

O objetivo é fazer com que a `div.rodape` esteja sempre o **final** da **página**.

Porém, quando o conteúdo da página não enche toda a página tenho um problema pois a `div.rodape` fica lá em cima como na **imagem** abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como fazer com que em qualquer situação, a `div.rodape` sempre esteja no **fim** da **página**?

Esse erro pode ser visto em

http://wesleyanagceu.com.br/

**Obs.:** Não gostaria de usar `position: fixed` e nem `position: absolute` por causa da posição fixa que isso gera.

Comment: @hugocsl, por favor, esse questão NÃO é duplicata pois não permite display: flex como solução. Por favor, desmarca ela como duplicata.

Comment: .cont {
 min-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
}

Comment: Carlos adicionei outra Duplicada que atende seu critério. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86214/97477

Comment: então, valeu, nas minhas tentativas fiz algo parecido com isso. fiz:  na ultima did margin-bottom: 0; e position: relative; e no 
html, body, {
    min-height:100%
}